# SQL rows from different tables

Tags: sql

I have two tables that I want information from. The name of the first table is Playing, the other is Game.

```
Player Game_ID Points

Game_ID Length Judged_by
```

I want to write an SQL query that only shows the players who have the same game_ID. And also the length of that game. I'm pretty new to SQL and don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite sure what you want to achive. If you want all users that have more that 1 game played use:

```
select p.player, g.game_id, g.length 
from game g
inner join playing p on g.game_id = p.game_id
group by game_id
having count(game_id) > 1
```

If you want all players that played a specific game then use (game_id is an example):

```
select p.player, g.game_id, g.length 
from game g
inner join playing p on g.game_id = p.game_id
where game_id = 123
```

### Edit

Here you go:

```
select p.player, g.game_id, g.length
from game g 
inner join playing p on g.game_id = p.game_id
where g.game_id in (  select g.game_id
                      from game g
                      inner join playing p on g.game_id = p.game_id
                      group by g.game_id
                      having count(p.game_id) > 1
                    )
order by g.game_id
```

Please see this [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dd539/9) to verify that it is working.

### Edit 2

I don't know the relation between `playing` and `players` table. I used columns `id` and `player` in this example to get the players name too:

```
select g.game_id, g.length, p.first_name, p.last_name
from game g 
inner join playing pg on g.game_id = pg.game_id
inner join Players p on p.id = pg.player
where g.game_id in (  select g.game_id
                      from game g
                      inner join playing pg on g.game_id = pg.game_id
                      group by g.game_id
                      having count(pg.game_id) > 1
                    )
order by g.game_id
```

### Last edit:

```
select g.game_id, g.length, p.first_name, p.last_name, j.Judge_firstname, j.Judge_lastname
from game g 
inner join playing pg on g.game_id = pg.game_id
inner join Players p on p.id = pg.player
inner join judges j on j.judge_id = g.judged_by
where g.game_id in (  select g.game_id
                      from game g
                      inner join playing pg on g.game_id = pg.game_id
                      where play_date > to_date('2012-05-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
                      group by g.game_id
                      having count(pg.game_id) > 1
                    )
order by g.game_id
```

See [this example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3711d/2)

Comment: Thanks, but I just edited the question.. I forgot one of the most important things I was looking for!

Comment: @user1390252: What did you forget?

Comment: Hmm, I did edit the question but still the old one was showing. Well, now I've edited again!

Comment: I'm using Oracle.

I want all games that more than one person are playing. The list that I want for an answer is supposed to show which players played together.

Comment: @user1390252: An example of the list that you want for an answer could be added to the question. :)

Comment: Thank you so much!!
That works fine.

Although.. I figured out I want the players name in the list too (column Player in Playing is only social security number). The players name is found in another table, called Players. The columns name are First_name and Last_name. Is there an easy way to add this to the answer?

Comment: That's great, thank you! Really appreciate it. Now I want to add two more things (didn't realize it from the beginning, otherwise I would have written it in the first question). 

I want only the games that have already been played to show. So I want to add something like this: WHERE Date < '2012-05-21';

Also, I want the judges name to show. In table Game, there's a column called judged_by. That's the judges ID. There's another table called Judges, with Judge_firstname and Judge_lastname. In that Judges-table there's also the judge_ID.

(I promise this is the last edit..)